# 2015 Moderator Candidate Activity Profiles

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I've generated weekly histograms of activity for each of the current [2015 election candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary), combining SO, MSO, and MSE activity. This data consists of the total counts, per week, of publicly available activity (reviews, revisions, comments, posts, accepts, suggests, badges) and is intended to represent general activity on the site and the metas.

**It excludes the following data, which is not available, and so may misrepresent some users activity profiles (i.e. take this data with a grain of salt!):**

- Votes
- Flags
- **All activity on deleted posts (a big one)**

This data was generated from the following sources:

- [This SEDE query](http://bit.ly/1CJyLcV) for everything except reviews.
- The ["reviews" tab on the user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

I capped the vertical range on the graphs to 800 weekly events, as some users had a couple of 1200+ week outliers here and there.

The horizontal and vertical range is the same for every graph. The graphs extend as far back as the earliest recorded event of all the current nominees (somewhere back in 2008).

[Raw data is available on GitHub](https://github.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/tree/master/data). The plots are there as well. Separate datasets are available there for SO, MSO, and MSE individually.

I will attempt to keep this post up to date throughout the election. I can only make updates on Mondays when the public data dump is refreshed.

Note that the very last, rightmost week on the graphs below is incorrect, as they include reviews (constantly up-to-date via profile) but no other events (not up-to-date from SEDE).

So, here are a ton of graphs! Yay, data! Graphs are presented in alphabetical order of user display name. The user's SO join date is shown as a vertical green marker; past elections (start and end dates) are shown as vertical orange markers. Click for higher resolution. Comments on graph formatting and visualization are welcome. Enjoy.

Since the total length of this post is long, here are direct links to the other datasets posted as answers below:

- [Moderator Activity Profiles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290057/616460)
- [Activity By Hour of Day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290419/616460)

Additional data:

- [Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) and [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone)'s excellent [election statistics summary page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow)
- [Ffisegydd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3005188/ffisegydd) put together some nice [additional graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8nMG.jpg) comparing users to each other.
- I've put together a [live voting monitor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290346/2015-election-live-vote-monitor). It's super fun to watch!
- Nomination comment threads and questionnaire responses are linked below. **Read them before you vote!**

---

[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29480018), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290122), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29480018)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-189134-Andy.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-189134-Andy.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-186281-Andy.csv.png)):[image: Andy]

[AstroCB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479232), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479232)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-3366929-AstroCB.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-3366929-AstroCB.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-258672-AstroCB.csv.png)):[image: AstroCB]

[codeMagic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380752/codemagic) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479499), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290476), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479499)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1380752-codeMagic.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1380752-codeMagic.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-225304-codeMagic.csv.png)):[image: codeMagic]

[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29485915), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290162), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29485915)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-476-deceze.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-476-deceze.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-476-deceze.csv.png)):[image: deceze]

[Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29552124), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290381), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29552124)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2057919-Ed%20Cottrell.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2057919-Ed%20Cottrell.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-238426-Ed%20Cottrell.csv.png)):[image: Ed Cottrell]

[Hemang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603234/hemang) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29523122), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29523122)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1603234-Hemang.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1603234-Hemang.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-199591-Hemang.csv.png)):[image: Hemang]

[hichris123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581872/hichris123) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29481172), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290129), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29481172)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2581872-hichris123.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2581872-hichris123.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-237685-hichris123.csv.png)):[image: hichris123]

[Idan Adar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1530814/idan-adar) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478809), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478809)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1530814-Idan%20Adar.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1530814-Idan%20Adar.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-212289-Idan%20Adar.csv.png)):[image: Idan Adar]

[Jason C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479047), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290142), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479047)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-616460-Jason%20C.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-616460-Jason%20C.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-230261-Jason%20C.csv.png)):[image: Jason C]

[Jeremy Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29528400), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29528400)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1114-Jeremy%20Banks.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1114-Jeremy%20Banks.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-134300-Jeremy%20Banks.csv.png)):[image: Jeremy Banks]

[Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478899), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290128), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478899)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1252759-Jon%20Clements.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1252759-Jon%20Clements.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-191185-Jon%20Clements.csv.png)):[image: Jon Clements]

[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479702), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290185), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479702)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-100297-Martijn%20Pieters.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-100297-Martijn%20Pieters.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-140890-Martijn%20Pieters.csv.png)):[image: Martijn Pieters]

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29565195), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290327), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29565195)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-444991-Matt.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-444991-Matt.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-163863-Matt.csv.png)):[image: Matt]

[meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479494), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290098), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479494)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-229044-meagar.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-229044-meagar.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-142838-meagar.csv.png)):[image: meagar]

[Michael Irigoyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542517/michael-irigoyen) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29480671), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290112), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29480671)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-542517-Michael%20Irigoyen.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-542517-Michael%20Irigoyen.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-154928-Michael%20Irigoyen.csv.png)):[image: Michael Irigoyen]

[Mooseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234256/mooseman) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478999), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290234), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478999)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1234256-Mooseman.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1234256-Mooseman.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-202832-Mooseman.csv.png)):[image: Mooseman]

[Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479205), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290199), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479205)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-224988-Moshe.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-224988-Moshe.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-142875-Moshe.csv.png)):[image: Moshe]

[Paresh Mayani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/paresh-mayani) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29508583), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29508583)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-379693-Paresh%20Mayani.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-379693-Paresh%20Mayani.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-149165-Paresh%20Mayani.csv.png)):[image: Paresh Mayani]

[Qantas 94 Heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074608/qantas-94-heavy) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29609910), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290204), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29609910)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2074608-Qantas%2094%20Heavy.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-2074608-Qantas%2094%20Heavy.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-220428-Qantas%2094%20Heavy.csv.png)):[image: Qantas 94 Heavy]

[Raghav Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29484189), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29484189)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1069068-Raghav%20Sood.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1069068-Raghav%20Sood.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-187954-Raghav%20Sood.csv.png)):[image: Raghav Sood]

[rekire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29486743), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290348), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29486743)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-995926-rekire.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-995926-rekire.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-171881-rekire.csv.png)):[image: rekire]

[Second Rikudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/second-rikudo) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478939), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290100), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478939)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-871050-Second%20Rikudo.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-871050-Second%20Rikudo.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-166899-Second%20Rikudo.csv.png)):[image: Second Rikudo]

[Sergey K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065190/sergey-k) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479010), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479010)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1065190-Sergey%20K..csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1065190-Sergey%20K..csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-186246-Sergey%20K..csv.png)):[image: Sergey K.]

[Shree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965146/shree) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29535261), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29535261)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-965146-Shree.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-965146-Shree.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-163529-Shree.csv.png)):[image: Shree]

[slugster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29482579), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290156), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29482579)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-109702-slugster.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-109702-slugster.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-146015-slugster.csv.png)):[image: slugster]

[Thomas Owens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572/thomas-owens) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478942), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290107), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478942)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-572-Thomas%20Owens.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-572-Thomas%20Owens.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-572-Thomas%20Owens.csv.png)):[image: Thomas Owens]

[Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479920), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290127), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479920)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1849664-Undo.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1849664-Undo.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-215468-Undo.csv.png)):[image: Undo]

[Unihedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedro) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478866), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478866)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-3622940-Unihedro.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-3622940-Unihedro.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-266094-Unihedro.csv.png)):[image: Unihedro]

[vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479035), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290111), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479035)) (Site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-492405-vcsjones.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-492405-vcsjones.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-155292-vcsjones.csv.png)):[image: vcsjones]

Comment: I'm concerned at Martijn's lack of activity in December 2013 for a brief period of time - do we really want a moderator that does that?

Comment: Also, IMO he shouldn't be a moderator at all, he should be an employee :)

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request]: this.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for doing this! Someone needs to go userscript this into the election page.

Comment: I was wondering about the decrease in activity at around the same time in many candidates, realized it was school starting.

Comment: @Undo Or generate them on the back-end periodically and add them to the elections stats page. It takes a decent amount of time to generate each graph: The query is pretty slow (although with incremental updates and a minimum date it speeds up), and the profile page scraping is extremely slow (I throttled to 2 second delays between tab pages, any faster and I was hitting temporary IP bans; e.g. Martijn has about 280 review tab pages = ~9-10 minutes).

Comment: I should note that it's *almost* pointless to even look at their review activity, because review actions on deleted posts eventually disappear from the activity history. In certain places, especially the Low Quality Posts queue which causes many posts to *get* deleted, almost all of their activity will eventually be erased from their "public history." I'm not sure about some of the events in your Data SE query, but they might suffer from the same "we can't see the ones on deleted content" problem.

Comment: Using the data @JasonC put together I made [some more graphs](http://imgur.com/a/3WR2U#0) which may be of interest. Primarily I plotted the "total" activity for all users on the same graph (what a mess of a plot!) as well as looking at the activity for all time for each user for each activity-type.

Comment: @animuson Thanks; I've edited to include that in the list of missing information. Everything here should be taken with a major grain of salt, there's a lot of missing info. It would be really interesting to see the activity profile with all of the private events in it as well. If only some SE employee wanted to provide sanitized event timestamps for flags, votes, and deleted reviews! Nudge nudge wink wink.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Cool!! I added a link to your graphs in the post, hope you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: I would consider reflecting candidates meta activity somehow (I suspect this will reveal yet another facet of [Martijn's negligence in December 2013](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289995/2015-moderator-nominee-activity-profiles#comment175556_289995))

Comment: I love all the little spikes around April 2015.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: the 2013 eggnog my wife made is still being talked about in hushed tones. It was an epic Christmas. I can now see there was a downside to that!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your concern about that.. People have lives, moderators take breaks. Moderation doesn't take the place of your real life. Vacations and holidays still happen. Do you expect your moderators to be 24/7 deletion machines? Because if so that just isn't realistic. Especially at the height of the (considered) biggest holiday of the year!

Comment: @Seth Yes, moderations should be 24/7 deletion machines, they should not have lives or take breaks >: ( . If they want to take breaks they should man (or woman) up and stop being a wuss about it. This is the internet and it's serious business, I take great offense in your comment and Martijn should write a formal apology letter for doing something other than SO if he expects to be taken seriously as a moderator. Please stop with your hippy jibby/jabber, we're trying to be professional here.

Comment: I have data for MSO and MSE now, and a set showing the total of all three. I am thinking of switching the plots to the combined set. It makes a small bit of difference for some of the candidates. Thoughts? Keep it as is or use the combined plots instead?

Comment: how about you show combined, and present links to separate plots for those interested in more detailed analysis?

Comment: [Martijn's plot seems to overflow](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/combined/plots-linear/activity-35417-Martijn%20Pieters.csv.png) (guess that's _yet another_ reason to consider him unsuitable candidate)

Comment: @gnat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/74583?m=22630829#22630829; we'll just have to accept that he's off the charts. He broke my plots; *definitely* shouldn't be a moderator.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to doctors.se because interpretation of an electrocardiography is better done by professionals (but check their meta and helpcenter first)

Comment: @gnat It's still quite weak. It's not even OVER 9000.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, but the balls are inert.

Comment: I'd love to see the how the current moderators stack up.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You should also make note on how the people who are running *weren't fully committed as real moderators* at the time. So of course, there contributions were voluntary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm your 900th vote, just saying. I was taken aback by how that chart got shattered by your activity and really impressed with how much you live on SO. Best of luck!

Comment: These graphs are amazing. Thanks for taking the time to make them!

Comment: I've updated the plot list for the primary phase, as well as added questionnaire links for candidates who have filled it out so far. I've left the nomination post links for easier access to nomination comments. I will try to update questionnaire links as quickly as possible as they are completed.

Comment: This influenced my primary voting, perhaps more than the candidate statements.  Not sure yet if that's good or bad.

Answer (score 43):

## Moderator Activity Profiles

For comparison, here is the same data for all current SO moderators, excluding employees. The graphs are the same scale and format as above. The [approximate date each user was made a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253240/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-when-a-moderator-was-elected-appointed#comment827241_253241) is marked by a vertical red bar.

As with the nominee graphs, this data does not include flags, votes, or activity on deleted posts. Additionally, it does not include any moderator-only activities that aren't publicly listed; so it might be the case that they are only directly comparable to the above prior to their election.

---

[0x7fffffff♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/) ([Elected Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-716216-0x7fffffff.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-716216-0x7fffffff.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-179833-0x7fffffff.csv.png)):[image: 0x7fffffff]

[Bill the Lizard♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/) ([Appointed May 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-new-community-moderators/)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1288-Bill%20the%20Lizard.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-1288-Bill%20the%20Lizard.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-1288-Bill%20the%20Lizard.csv.png)):[image: Bill the Lizard]

[bluefeet♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/) ([Elected Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-426671-bluefeet.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-426671-bluefeet.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-164200-bluefeet.csv.png)):[image: bluefeet]

[Bohemian♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/) ([Elected Feb 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-256196-Bohemian.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-256196-Bohemian.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-166442-Bohemian.csv.png)):[image: Bohemian]

[BoltClock♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/) ([Elected Nov 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-106224-BoltClock.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-106224-BoltClock.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-137537-BoltClock.csv.png)):[image: BoltClock]

[Brad Larson♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/) ([Elected Jun 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-19679-Brad%20Larson.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-19679-Brad%20Larson.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-135615-Brad%20Larson.csv.png)):[image: Brad Larson]

[casperOne♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/) ([Elected Nov 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-50776-casperOne.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-50776-casperOne.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-140951-casperOne.csv.png)):[image: casperOne]

[ChrisF♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/) ([Elected Mar 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-59303-ChrisF.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-59303-ChrisF.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-59303-ChrisF.csv.png)):[image: ChrisF]

[Flexo♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/) ([Elected Mar 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-168175-Flexo.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-168175-Flexo.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-153020-Flexo.csv.png)):[image: Flexo]

[George Stocker♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/) ([Elected Jun 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-16587-George%20Stocker.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-16587-George%20Stocker.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-16587-George%20Stocker.csv.png)):[image: George Stocker]

[Gordon♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/) ([Elected Mar 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-208809-Gordon.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-208809-Gordon.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-168606-Gordon.csv.png)):[image: Gordon]

[Michael Myers♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/) ([Appointed Jul 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/summer-2010-moderator-appointments/)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-13531-Michael%20Myers.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-13531-Michael%20Myers.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-13531-Michael%20Myers.csv.png)):[image: Michael Myers]

[minitech♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/) ([Elected Mar 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-707111-minitech.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-707111-minitech.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-160410-minitech.csv.png)):[image: minitech]

[Robert Harvey♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/) ([Elected Feb 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-102937-Robert%20Harvey.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-102937-Robert%20Harvey.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-102937-Robert%20Harvey.csv.png)):[image: Robert Harvey]

[ThiefMaster♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/) ([Elected Jun 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3)) (Individual site plot: [SO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/stackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-298479-ThiefMaster.csv.png), [MSO](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackoverflow/plots-linear/activity-298479-ThiefMaster.csv.png), [MSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/metastackexchange/plots-linear/activity-147015-ThiefMaster.csv.png)):[image: ThiefMaster]

Comment: This is very nice because (among other reasons) it shows several examples of visible activity _dropping_ after a member becomes a moderator. Otherwise I think people might be tempted to just vote for the people with the highest activity levels without putting much more thought into it.

Comment: @DavidZ Also, these graphs don't show *moderator* activity, so handling flags, etc. is not visible. I would expect to see a decline in publicly visible activity after a moderator is elected, as that activity is hypothetically replaced by moderator duties. Moderators who *maintained* their public activity level after an election are interesting. I would love to recreate these graphs with private data. I did submit a request to support. It went expectedly unanswered. I have a feeling whoever got the email had to clean their coffee off their shirt afterwards.

Answer (score 13):

## Activity By Time of Day

Here I've put together punchcard style diagrams showing each candidate's activity level by day of week and time of day. All times are UTC.

Even though this only includes publicly available data, it should still serve as a decent representation of general activity times, based on the assumption the publicly available activity levels are strongly correlated with the unavailable data.

The data in these plots only includes activities in the past year. This makes them slightly more recent and also decreases spread due to e.g. people moving to other timezones. Additionally, the data does *not* include activity from the past three weeks. This is intended to reduce influence caused by election-inspired activity rushes.

I've chosen neutral colors for the plots below so as not to imply "good" vs. "bad". I've also scaled the circles in each plot relative to each candidate's own maximum value per day: the focus of these is on activity times, not relative activity levels between candidates (look at the other plots here for that info).

I've also generated a plot of the combination of all of the current moderators, for comparison with the candidates below, to try to visualize where the current gaps in coverage are:

[image: All Moderators]

Individual plots for the candidates are below. As with all the other images on this page, click the image for a larger view.

---

[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29480018), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290122), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29480018)):[image: Andy]

[AstroCB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479232), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479232)):[image: AstroCB]

[codeMagic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380752/codemagic) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479499), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290476), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479499)):[image: codeMagic]

[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29485915), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290162), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29485915)):[image: deceze]

[Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29552124), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290381), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29552124)):[image: Ed Cottrell]

[Hemang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603234/hemang) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29523122), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29523122)):[image: Hemang]

[hichris123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581872/hichris123) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29481172), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290129), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29481172)):[image: hichris123]

[Idan Adar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1530814/idan-adar) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478809), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478809)):[image: Idan Adar]

[Jason C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479047), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290142), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479047)):[image: Jason C]

[Jeremy Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29528400), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29528400)):[image: Jeremy Banks]

[Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478899), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290128), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478899)):[image: Jon Clements]

[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479702), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290185), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479702)):[image: Martijn Pieters]

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29565195), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290327), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29565195)):[image: Matt]

[meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479494), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290098), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479494)):[image: meagar]

[Michael Irigoyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542517/michael-irigoyen) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29480671), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290112), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29480671)):[image: Michael Irigoyen]

[Mooseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234256/mooseman) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478999), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290234), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478999)):[image: Mooseman]

[Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479205), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290199), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479205)):[image: Moshe]

[Paresh Mayani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/paresh-mayani) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29508583), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29508583)):[image: Paresh Mayani]

[Qantas 94 Heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074608/qantas-94-heavy) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29609910), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290204), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29609910)):[image: Qantas 94 Heavy]

[Raghav Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29484189), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29484189)):[image: Raghav Sood]

[rekire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29486743), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290348), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29486743)):[image: rekire]

[Second Rikudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/second-rikudo) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478939), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290100), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478939)):[image: Second Rikudo]

[Sergey K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065190/sergey-k) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479010), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479010)):[image: Sergey K.]

[Shree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965146/shree) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29535261), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29535261)):[image: Shree]

[slugster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29482579), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290156), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29482579)):[image: slugster]

[Thomas Owens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572/thomas-owens) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478942), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290107), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478942)):[image: Thomas Owens]

[Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479920), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290127), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479920)):[image: Undo]

[Unihedro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedro) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29478866), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29478866)):[image: Unihedro]

[vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones) ([Nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination&all=true#post-29479035), [Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290111), [Primary](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=primary#post-29479035)):[image: vcsjones]