# Only 10% voted this time, How to increase total number of votes/ voters in next election?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

At the end [results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results) are declared. Congrats to new moderators.

One bad thing is that for this election is, there 272,611 voters were eligible and voted only just 27,019. Meaning is that out of total eligible voters only [Approx **10%** of voters used their vote](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6).

Even surprising is the fact that only 78,870 visited the election page, So 1. We have two problems now, How to increase the election page visits next time ?, and,
2. How to convert this page visits to meaningful votes in next election ?

Please give your suggestions,

Comment: Do you have a question? Posts on Meta still need to be addressed as a question. Are you asking about how to make users vote, why so few people vote, or something else?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy my question is why so few votes? Sorry, forget to mention that.

Comment: It's actually higher than it used to be. In the [2013 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4), only 4.7% of eligible users voted.

Comment: Not all eligible voters actually visited the site so your 10% is a little disingenuous, not that it's hugely better at ~18% if you only count people online.

Comment: You haven't explained why 10% **is bad**. There's nothing stopping people voting, and they have every right to *not* vote. In fact, not voting could be considered an implicit statement that they don't care or are not concerned about who is moderating the site.

Comment: I'm really confused why this is closed, let alone accumulating delete votes. This has a specific question for the SO community, which is exactly what meta is for. _If_ the OP doesn't know some of the history then you can be sure others don't know either and this is a good place to educate.

Comment: Why do we downvote questions like this? Seems fairly benign to me lol .... seriously y'all calm down with the downvotes. OP's not trying to pull anything major here.  just inquiring of whoever wants to volunteer info... oh but of course *on meta, downvotes are different* smh

Comment: @ketan  - Actually, 10% of StackOverflow users *is* a pretty good turnout. there's also the notion from government history about an "ruling elite" vs the "ignorant masses" -  see U.S. Electoral College. The summary is that - more isn't necessarily better.  If we forced more people to vote, we might also get more uneducated votes...

Comment: Who gives a crap? I only want people who care to vote.  If you don't care, go sip your coffee.  Stay away. it's fine. No need to force idiots , er I mean people who don't or can't care to participate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I whipped out a small chart of previous election turn outs. The chart below shows the percentage of voters in relation to

- Total Eligible (bottom layer)
- Number of users that visited the site (this information isn't available for the January 2011 election)
- Number of users that visited the election site

[image: Previous Election Comparisons]
<sub>(click for a larger image)</sub>

---

You can see that all three metrics went down over the course of the first 4 elections. In 2014, there was a very nice spike in percentage of voters (nearing the percentages set in the first election).

When comparing this election to the first election (and the one with the highest voting percentage in both the eligible users and voters who visited the election site), we see that this year was very close to matching those values.

- There are **6** times as many eligible voters in April 2015 as there were in January 2011. Yet, the percentage of eligible voters who voted is less than **1.5%** different (9.9% in 2015 vs 11.3% in 2011).
- There were almost **6** times as many visits to the election page in April 2015 as there were in January 2011. The percentage of these users that voted is less than **1.2%** different.

---

To me, it looks like the vote percentages we are seeing is higher than average (accounting for the dip between Nov 2011 and Feb 2013). April 2015 just *barely* missed setting records.

While 34% (visited election site) or 18% (active and eligible) turn out may seem low, it is important to remember that voting isn't compulsory. User may not be interested in the Meta portion of Stack Overflow at all, thus don't cast a ballot. Other may look at the walls of text presented by nominees during the [nomination phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination) or the even longer walls of text presented during the [primaries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/189134) and give up. If someone truly wants to have an informed opinion on where the nominees stand, that is a lot of reading.

I think part of what helps users to form opinions is feedback from the voters themselves. Feedback on the nominations, on the primary questionnaire, on [applications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290346/189134) developed by users to encourage participation, [other information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289995/189134) provided by [users](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow) to help differentiate nominees. Encouraging all of this helps get people involved.

---

A couple other things I noticed that are unrelated to the election, but are relevant to the site in general:

- April 2015 had a lower percentage of eligible voters than the previous election (9.9% vs 10.7%)
- The percentage of eligible users that visited in April 2015 and the previous election are very similar (18.1% vs 17.8%). Despite having nearly 72K more eligible users, the percentage of users with at least 150 reputation that utilized Stack Overflow remained constant.

Comment: I initially thought that the Constituent badge (which arguably is about the easiest silver badge ever) might have something to do with the improved numbers. But based on some searching, it was introduced in June 2012, which was before the Feb 2013 election that has the lowest participation. So there's no convincing evidence that it has anything to do with people liking shiny pixels.

Comment: +1 because those were some *serious* walls of text. I'm a very fast reader and I spend hours on the site every day, a fair amount of that on Meta, but I didn't have time to do all the research I wanted and ended up putting my votes in with half an hour to spare.

Comment: I voted and what was especially time consuming is that many of the answers received from the questions posed to the candidates were very similar. I found it very difficult to differentiate between them because of this. Maybe the type of the questions could be improved on since it seemed more like a "quiz" than a way to help the electorate reach an informed decision. I found the blurb written by each of the candidates to be more useful than the Q&A in many cases.

Answer (score 10):

The raw numbers for the 6 moderator elections:

```
Election   Visitors   Seen it  Candidates Voters  Participation
   #1        ~25000     14130     55        4970      20/35%
   #2         45177     17866     28        4994      11/28%
  2012        60208     19479     18        4426       7/23%
  2013        87022     33846     27        6574       8/19%
  2014       121419     65118     30       21571      18/33%
  2015       149240     78870     32       27019      18/34%
```

The big jump in 2014 is almost certainly attributable to SO getting its own meta, along with better advertizing in the side-bar.  Nothing wrong with these numbers, participation is quite healthy compared to the 2012/3 years.

Comment: For clarity here: "Visitors" is _site_ visitors? "Seen it" means "went to the election page"? And the two participation percentages are thus "viewed the election"/"voted" out of the visitors?

Comment: Yes.  Visitors are people that *could* have known about the election.  And yes.  And yes.

Answer (score 2):

There are three groups:

1. Those who don't care to vote
2. Those who vote
3. Those who don't feel qualified to vote

You probably can't do anything about #1 and you don't need to do anything about #2. But for #3, I suspect more would vote if they had a basis to make a choice. So give them information. I guess that would be campaigning. It's possible there is campaigning and I don't know about it. But I can tell you from a user experience standpoint as someone firmly in the #3 camp, I looked when I was asked to vote and I had no basis to choose so I left without voting.

Comment: Personally, I based my vote mainly on interactions I had on this meta.  Perhaps encouraging more meta participation would help the #3's.  That almost feels like preaching to the choir though, so I'm not sure how effective that would be.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

How about posting an explicit call to do a specific thing?

The announcement I received in my inbox did not unambiguously inform me of the specific action I as a voter should take, as far as I could see. Particularly, the [place I landed](https://stackoverflow.com/election) when I clicked through the notice in my inbox did not say anything as specific as "go to your preferred candidate's profile and click on the button" or "up-vote your preferred candidate's statement", never mind "you only have one vote" or "use your ten votes wisely".

If a voter doesn't know what to do, they won't participate.

Answer (score -5):

As others have pointed out, there is not a demonstrable correlation between voter turnout and quality of elections.

But 10% happens to be a nice  number on StackOverflow, as it catches only 10% of users with at least 150 rep , *who decided to vote* .  This is not the drive-by newbie , rather - someone who spent at least an hour here