# Visualizing Data About Stack Overflow Election Candidates

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

When reading up on all the candidates in the moderator election, I found myself wanting to know how candidates compare on a lot of different numeric metrics, such as volume of edits, reviews, and helpful flags as well as post counts on the main site, meta.so, and meta.se. While these numeric metrics certainly don't capture the full picture of the candidates, I think they can provide some insight into how they use Stack Overflow in similar or different ways.

While the [Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow) provides a number of statistics about each candidate and is a fantastic resource for learning about each of the candidates individually, I find it a bit challenging to visualize how the candidates compare across the different metrics displayed in this list-based format. As a result, I created a d3.js-based visualization tool to compare candidates across 43 different numeric metrics. Some of the folks in the [Fall 2015 Moderator Election Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94634/fall-2015-moderator-election-chat) thought the tool was helpful for visualizing the candidates (and also provided great bug finds and feature suggestions -- thanks to [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy), [Ed Cottrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell), [rekire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire), and [Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo)!), so I wanted to share it with the community for use in the current election and to get feedback about how it could be improved to better visualize information about candidates.

The site is available at http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html and the source code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/josilber/StackOverflowElectionViewer). As described on the [data details page](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/data.html), most of the data is from SEDE queries, though helpful flag count and review count are from user profiles and primary score is from [Undo's tracker](http://soprimaries.erwaysoftware.com/). Candidates are plotted as circles of various colors, and current moderators are plotted as white circles.

Here is an example screenshot from the tool, plotting post body edits, helpful flag count, and review count across the candidates in the final phase of the election and current moderators:

[image]

Using the controls on the right, you can adjust which users are displayed and which of the 43 variables is plotted on the x-axis, on the y-axis, and as the circle sizes. You can hover over points to get a tooltip that identifies the user and gives the exact value of the three variables being displayed; hovering also bolds the user's name in the list on the right. The permalink enables you to share any interesting variable sets via a link (e.g. you can access the plot above [here](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=BodyEdits&y=HelpfulFlags&r=ReviewCount&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_476_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_2422776_995926_102937_109702_298479_572_1849664_2193767)).

I would love to hear any feedback about any bugs and about how the tool could be expanded to better visualize the candidates (either through new variables or UI improvements).

**Update:** Following an excellent suggestion in the comments by [pnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts), I updated the tool to enable adding a single additional user who is neither a current candidate nor a current moderator through the [Add a point link](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/plotMe.html); this can be used for instance by any user to add themselves to the plot. As an example, here is the plot with moderating legend [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) added ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=BodyEdits&y=HelpfulFlags&r=ReviewCount&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_476_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_2422776_995926_102937_109702_298479_572_1849664_2193767_1288000&u=%7B%22Id%22:%221288000%22,%22Reputation%22:%22190439%22,%22CandidateScore%22:%2240%22,%22DisplayName%22:%22Bill%20the%20Lizard%22,%22MonthsOnSite%22:%2287%22,%22UpVotes%22:%2215228%22,%22DownVotes%22:%2213677%22,%22Votes%22:%2228905%22,%22HelpfulFlags%22:%222981%22,%22ReviewCount%22:%2214659%22,%22QuestionCount%22:%2269%22,%22AnswerCount%22:%221628%22,%22GoldBadges%22:%22125%22,%22SilverBadges%22:%22424%22,%22BronzeBadges%22:%22714%22,%22CommentCount%22:%223253%22,%22BodyEdits%22:%229997%22,%22TitleEdits%22:%221472%22,%22TagEdits%22:%224342%22,%22UpVotesMSO%22:%222464%22,%22DownVotesMSO%22:%221258%22,%22VotesMSO%22:%223722%22,%22QuestionCountMSO%22:%224%22,%22AnswerCountMSO%22:%22283%22,%22GoldBadgesMSO%22:%2223%22,%22SilverBadgesMSO%22:%22168%22,%22BronzeBadgesMSO%22:%22174%22,%22CommentCountMSO%22:%22902%22,%22DiscussionScoreMSO%22:%225169%22,%22FeatureRequestScoreMSO%22:%22568%22,%22SupportScoreMSO%22:%22372%22,%22ReputationMSE%22:%22116414%22,%22UpVotesMSE%22:%2210061%22,%22DownVotesMSE%22:%221619%22,%22VotesMSE%22:%2211680%22,%22QuestionCountMSE%22:%2248%22,%22AnswerCountMSE%22:%221258%22,%22GoldBadgesMSE%22:%2252%22,%22SilverBadgesMSE%22:%22263%22,%22BronzeBadgesMSE%22:%22556%22,%22CommentCountMSE%22:%223493%22,%22DiscussionScoreMSE%22:%229055%22,%22FeatureRequestScoreMSE%22:%221766%22,%22SupportScoreMSE%22:%222034%22%7D)):

[image]

Comment: This is some excellent information right there. It's kind of a shame to see how little meta participation some of the candidates have, though.

Comment: Related, from last election: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289995/2015-moderator-candidate-activity-profiles I still have the tools could probably do one for this election too.

Comment: That's some nice work there, and I like how you have included metrics from Meta.SO and Meta.SE. Can you change the default metric selection to *Edit to Question Title (Main Page)* - I'm awesome in that one!

Comment: @slugster Thanks for the feedback! I thought about this some more and concluded that the best way to set the initial variables is to select them randomly from the full set of variables, because this doesn't prioritize any particular variable (as a bonus, it makes it much more fun to repeatedly refresh the page). This change is live on the site now.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a side-by-side comparison between mod candidates and existing mods.

Comment: @BilltheLizard excellent point! It will take me a bit of time to pull that data together, but I should be able to get that up by the afternoon/evening (EST).

Comment: @josilber It would be especially interesting to see those stats as of when the mods were elected, rather than as of today. I realize most mods don't spend much time raising flags as opposed to handling them, but spam flags in particular will skew the stats. That said, I don't know where you're finding time to do this much with this tool anyway, so feel free to disregard this.

Comment: @EdCottrell great idea, but unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to present data from when the current moderators were elected. The reason is that the SEDE queries I use to get the data can only access current information.

Comment: @josilber Fair enough.

Comment: @BilltheLizard the comparison between statistics of candidates and existing mods is now live.

Comment: @pnuts Really interesting suggestion, though unfortunately it's fairly non-trivial due to the reliance of the tool on SEDE queries. I can envision a scheme in which I give you SEDE queries to run (providing relevant parameters such as user id), you download the results to CSV files, and you finally upload those files, enabling me to plot your information along with everybody else. I'll try to get that up and running tonight (EST)!

Comment: @pnuts I added the functionality to add a single non-candidate to the plot -- you can use it by clicking the [add a point](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/plotMe.html) link on the site, and it will guide you through the steps to get your information plotted.

Comment: When I mouse-overed Andy in [the link you gave](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=BodyEdits&y=HelpfulFlags&r=ReviewCount&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_476_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_2422776_995926_102937_109702_298479_572_1849664_2193767) thought he wasn't visible because of someone's dot covering his. Then I clicked on him and was... surprised :P

Comment: @fermiparadox by default I only have the finalists in the current election displayed from the candidate list, which is why Andy didn't show up for you when you visited the link. As you note he has a really spectacular helpful flag count, in part due to some [great work he has done on automatically flagging comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/3093387).

Answer (score 17):

I found a few settings that show interesting outliers between the candidates. I based these on the current primary score, so the highest voters are to the far right of the graph. The circle sizes are reputation.

- [Edits to Question Title](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=TitleEdits&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVZhK.png)*) - **slugster**
- Compare this to [edits to post body](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=BodyEdits&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdxQE.png)*) and [post tags](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=TagEdits&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDI67.png)*)- **Mureinik**
- [Answer count](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=AnswerCount&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4Yy.png)*) and [comment count](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=CommentCount&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4lRw.png)*) goes to **deceze** (who also has the highest rep)
- But, [highest number of gold badges](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=GoldBadges&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZKr5.png)*) goes to **Thomas Owens**, beating deceze by almost 30 badges
- [Flag count](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=HelpfulFlags&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCo9Y.png)*) goes to **Andy**, with the top three in the primary standing out as well.
- [Review count](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=ReviewCount&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GeSO.png)*) has three users that stick out: **Andy**, **Mureinik** and **Undo**

Finally, one observation that I found interesting is that most candidates have [less than 5 years experience](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=primary&y=MonthsOnSite&r=Reputation&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767) (*[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvirD.png)*) on Stack Overflow with the top three having three or less.

I am still looking at various combinations of numbers, but the outliers are interesting too. It's interesting to see what candidates have "specialized" in, regarding moderation actions.

Comment: Just as a point of comparison, I had far less than 5 years of experience on the site when I first became an SO moderator. ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'd remind you of [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results#comment180512_291036). I didn't get to join in the round of comments when you stepped down, but I'll say it now: thank you. You are an inspiration.