# How might I better prepare myself for the next moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-election

I've been a Stack Overflow user for more than 6 years and I've seen many moderator elections. Like many, each election wakes up an urge inside to run for moderator.

I'll usually write my pitch, using what other moderators have called out as valuable skills in addition to a few of my own. I've got pretty decent rep, have been a member for a while, and am active. (Arguably, nowhere near as much I was during the first two or so years I was around.)

It usually happens that I'll do okay for a while, but then it become obvious that I'm not as qualified as some of the other candidates.

So, in addition to everything in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), what might I do to become a better and more viable candidate? How can I use my desire to moderate as a springboard for personal growth as a member of the Stack Overflow community? Finally, are the criteria that go into the moderator score listed anywhere?

Comment: Related: ["What to do to boost your chances of becoming an SO moderator?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188288/what-to-do-to-boost-your-chances-of-becoming-an-so-moderator)

Comment: Come to Lounge C++

Comment: Be active within the community, answering questions, asking questions, taking part in meta discussions, etc. If a large number of people already recognize your name *in a positive way*, that'd likely help your chances quite a bit. but.... that's not something that will happen over night.

Comment: What role does the review queue and flagging play?

Comment: A huge role for me. Any candidate that didn't spend time on  reviewing won't get my vote.

Comment: Much of it ultimately comes down to the candidate score numbers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah, actually for the past 2 elections every single elected moderator had a perfect 40/40 candidate score.

Comment: Where is the candidate score explained?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/186281 provides an explanation of candidate score criteria

Comment: Don't go to Lounge C++

Comment: @Moshe For me the review queues are very important when voting, since moderation largely consists of review like tasks. If you haven't spent time in the review queues I will (perhaps incorrectly) assume that you are not interested in doing the boring janitorial repetitive tasks but more interested in the shine diamon. Right now you have 107 reviews. Go get 2k+, perhaps earning a couple of gold badges. That would at least impress me.

Comment: @Moshe: Here's a query to calculate your own: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score

Comment: Be more active, edit more, answer more, be helpful and work the queues.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is one obvious step: Try and get a candidate score of 40/40 or as close to it as you can (if you haven't already).

To pick an example at random, here's one from the recent election:

```
candidate score 33/40
reputation >= 20k
moderation badges: 4/8
editing badges: 4/6
participation badges: 5/6
```

Given that there are other candidates with a score of 40 then unless there is something absolutely "wow" in the blurb then why would I ever pick this person who has less than 40? In particular they have only 50% of the moderation badges and 66% of the editing ones...

Unless I recognize the name or know the person I have no evidence to go on except the candidate score and the written statement and the score is an objective measure of just how much moderation you are already doing and how much experience you have with it.

Being active in meta and having a high flag clear rate shows that you are already moderating so doing that and making sure you declare it in your description will help.

Being a moderator on one of the smaller sites may help as well since it shows you will have experience with the tools and what is involved. (Although some people may count it against you as you might not have time to moderate both sites effectively).

To give a specific example, in the most recent election my votes went to:

- 1 person who's name I recognized from various meta posts, who had moderating experience on other SE sites, etc and who I had a generally positive impression of.
- 2 people who had a score of near 40 (might have been 38 or 39, certainly not lower), high flag/queue activity and a well written manifesto.

Anyone with <20k rep, <1 year on the site or <38 score wasn't even in the running given the number of extremely high quality candidates.

If you look at the results of the election this theory is if not proved then at least encouraged. There were 4 candidates with 40/40 score and all 3 winners were in that 4. And the same was true of the previous election, all 3 winners had 40/40 score (I didn't look at how many others had 40/40).

Comment: *Unless I recognize the name or know the person* ... Leaving a comment here, so everyone can recognize me :D

Comment: @BhargavRao Better off getting your candidate score up - look at the edit I just added :)

Comment: Minor nitpick - I had (have) <20k *and* <38 candidate score, and yet [I still managed third in primaries](http://soprimaries.erwaysoftware.com) by a decent margin. I also got fifth in the final election (which I like to think gives me a historically good chance of being pulled up later). I was definitely in the running - just didn't run fast enough.

Comment: You were the non 40/40  I voted for so I hold you up as the exception not the rule ;)  Also while you did well in the primaries you still fell at the final hurdle. If you were 40/40 I'm fairly confident you'd have got in.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! My goal is 40/40 by next election, we'll see if I get there ;)

Comment: @Undo I actually interpret your non-election as proof that a non perfect 40 candidate score makes it nearly impossible to get elected.  For some reason, people voted differently in the primaries than the final election.  I think it's a voter turnout thing, but it's still strange that you received the 5th most sum of 1st, 2nd, 3rd place votes in the final election.

Comment: I'm fine with a few points short of 40; my voting algorithm is roughly (1) narrow to the ones I know and trust; (2) compare their scores. But frequently, there will be enough 40/40 candidates even in my narrowed-down set to receive all my votes. (@Undo certainly made it through (1), and very nearly through (2).)

Comment: Getting a high score basically is synonymous to participating a lot. I actually try not to put too much weight on the score since it is only a number, especially I don't care if the score is 38 or 40. Looking at contributions is for example a much easier way to judge the character of someone.

Comment: This whole "omg you must get high score lol" nonsense is directly analogous to the "omg you must get top grades" school exam problem. It is **far** from the most important measure, in an intelligent world.

Comment: And yet we don't live in an intelligent world. Additionally, in a situation where there are too many options to give all candidates full attention it's a useful filter to use in order to reduce the option set down to a manageable number. Which is why grades matter...it gets you through more filters...you can be the best person for the job but if you don't have the grades you will never get the chance to prove that.

Answer (score 25):

I think the advice from Tim B regarding candidate score is really solid, because that metric is prominently displayed on the election page. More broadly, I think the community favors candidates who have a strong moderation track record. I'll include data from current moderators (those elected in the most recent election are the colored points) across a few relevant metrics:

## Edits

Most moderators have performed much more than the 500 edits required to get the copy editor badge ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=BodyEdits&y=TagEdits&r=TitleEdits&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_102937_298479)):

[image]

Here's the statistics just for the candidates in the most recent election, with the three who were elected freehand labeled ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=BodyEdits&y=TagEdits&r=TitleEdits&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767)):

[image]

## Flags and reviews

Most moderators have raised a large number of helpful flags and have performed many reviews ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=HelpfulFlags&y=ReviewCount&r=CandidateScore&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_102937_298479))

[image]

Here's the statistics just for the candidates in the most recent election, with the three who were elected freehand labeled ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=HelpfulFlags&y=ReviewCount&r=CandidateScore&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767))

[image]

## Meta Participation

Some but not all moderators have huge meta participation ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=AnswerCountMSO&y=GoldBadgesMSO&r=ReputationMSE&c=716216_256196_106224_19679_50776_59303_2057919_168175_16587_208809_1114_1252759_3093387_871050_100297_444991_229044_13531_707111_102937_298479)):

[image]

Here's the statistics just for the candidates in the most recent election, with the three who were elected freehand labeled ([permalink](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html?x=AnswerCountMSO&y=GoldBadgesMSO&r=ReputationMSE&c=189134_2371861_1380752_476_2057919_2174085_3093387_871050_2422776_995926_109702_774078_572_1026459_1952862_1849664_2301450_2193767))

[image]

You can explore these and other characteristics of the moderator candidates from the recent election and current moderators at http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/SOelection.html ([meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310694)), and you can add yourself to the visualization with the [add a point](http://josilber.scripts.mit.edu/SOElection/plotMe.html) link.

Comment: Is there any way to highlight the ones that got elected?

Comment: @TimB the answer says "current moderators" so they all did.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ahh. What might be more interesting then is a similar graph for the last couple of elections for all candidates - but with the ones that got elected highlighted in a different color. That should allow correlations to be seen visually to compare ones that got in and didn't.

Comment: @TimB I added in the plots with just the moderator candidates from the last election, with the ones who won highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, good stuff. I think that's interesting in that it shows that a certain level of engagement is needed but beyond that further increases in scores don't seem to help.

Answer (score 5):

The first and most obvious thing I can tell you is that you should use the site more. You've been on Stack Overflow for 6 years, that's roughly the same amount of time as me. Yet, I've performed [21,198](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar?tab=activity) actions to your [5,579](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224988/moshe?tab=activity). I'm not trying to boast or declare that I'm a good measuring stick for a moderator; I don't consider myself an abnormally avid user. But, engagement matters; I think people want to see both a high reputation *and* a track record of moderation activities.

The second thing I can tell you that I *think* helped my chances (though I have no way of gauging how effective it was): Answer the Q&A meta post *quickly*. You'll notice that the in [meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290096/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/290098#290098) for the election in which I ran, I posted my responses *7 minutes* after the question was asked. I assumed that *all* the candidates would similarly be waiting for that post, and that they'd have their responses ready. After all, we all knew it was coming, and we all knew what questions would be on it because [they're submitted by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289449/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), so there was *tones* of time to prepare our answers.

So, my post was first, and that meant people could vote on it first. By the time other answers started appearing, I already had some upvotes, and while every other page relating to the election sorts candidates randomly, *that page is sorted by votes*, so the whole "fastest gun in the west" thing is (like it or not) going to happen. My response (starting with a link directly to my nomination where you could vote for me) stayed at the top for the *entire election*; answers posted the next day were so far down the page, buried under so many long response, that I think very few people actually scrolled down to read them. Many people probably assumed the top couple of posts were the best and (if anything) added *more* upvotes to them, insuring they'd stay on top.

Again, there's no hard data to tell whether this helped, and the second answer (chronologically) was from a candidate who was not elected. I would just recommend paying attention and answering early, rather than answering days after the fact when your responses will be at the bottom of a **huge** page, and far fewer users will see them.