# What is the purpose of user feed?

Tags: discussion, support

In my profile page, I can see a link labelled "User Feed", and it opens an XML document. What is the purpose of it? If it is meant for us to use in our personal blog or something, how can I use it?

Example: [https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/{user_id}](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/%7Buserid%7D)

Comment: It's an RSS feed.  You can use it for whatever you want to use it for.

Comment: can I directly parse it? whether SO reject the request?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318543/user-rss-feeds-feeding-the-hand-that-bites-you

Comment: Sure you can parse it.  It's a standard format; again, it's an RSS feed.  Why would SO reject the request?

Comment: ok. thank you for the information @Servy

Comment: @Servy that sounds something to put in an answer * nudge nudge wink wink *

Comment: How to use that to follow the user?